# Get non constrained columns in Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

This query

```
select rdb$field_name from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name='YOUR-TABLE_NAME';
```

perfectly finds all column names from specific table. And the question is it possible to alter that query so it ignores all columns which are key or foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

The basic task is to find out which fields are not associated with a constraint. If we only go for primary key, unique key and foreign key constraints, then you need to look at the table [`RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-relconstr) and [`RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-idxsegments) (you can skip [`RDB$INDICES`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-indices)) to find out which columns are used in one of those types of constraints.

For primary key, foreign key or unique key constraints, the `RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS` has the `RDB$INDEX_NAME` populated pointing to the index backing the constraint. From the `RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS` table, you can then find the columns involved in the constraint.

You can find all columns of tables (or views) in [`RDB$RELATION_FIELDS`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx04-relfields), and then it is a matter of excluding those fields that are used in a constraint.

The result is a query like:

```sql
select rf.RDB$RELATION_NAME, rf.RDB$FIELD_NAME
from RDB$RELATION_CONSTRAINTS rc
inner join RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS iseg
  on iseg.RDB$INDEX_NAME = rc.RDB$INDEX_NAME
right join RDB$RELATION_FIELDS rf
  on rf.RDB$RELATION_NAME = rc.RDB$RELATION_NAME and rf.RDB$FIELD_NAME = iseg.RDB$FIELD_NAME 
where rf.RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE'
and rc.RDB$CONSTRAINT_NAME is null
```